# how to enable selectManyListBox scrollerbar when readonly attribute is true in JSF?

Tags: jsf

I am using `<h:selectManyListBox>` in my project. In view mode my component was

disabled including the scrollbar of that component.But i want to enable the scrollbar

of that component in view mode and values should be in non-editable mode

I have used `readOnly` attribute in `<h:selectManyListBox>`,

Please Help me....

Answer (score 2):

As specified in [its TLDDOC](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.2_MR1/docs/tlddocs/h/selectManyListbox.html), just set the `size` attribute accordingly. It denotes the number of options shown at once. If not specified, then all options will be shown at once.

If you want to show 1 option while the fictive boolean expression `#{bean.readonly}` returns true, then you can make use of the ternary operator `expr ? doThisIfTrue : orDoThisIfFalse` in EL:

```
<h:selectManyListbox size="#{bean.readonly ? '1' : ''}">
```

Comment: Hi BalusC,

Sorry for tat...i have deleted tat answer

Can u explain in detail?

Suppose i have 100 entries in my h:SelectManyListBox , 
i'm selecting 10 values from the

List and i want to view Selected values 
from the 100 entries in view Page(ReadOnly

Mode).So my requirement is to enable the 
scrollbar of h:SelectManyListBox in view Page.

Thanks, Ramesh

Comment: Then just set the `size` attribute accordingly? If you want to display only 10 items at once, set it to 10.